# Plotting each inner-inner member of a list as a line in a line plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of two.
The list x contains `x$t` and `x$y`. Inside y there is: `y0, y1, y2, y3, z0, z1, z2, z3`.

I want to create a plot that has 3 lines:

- one line is: y0
- one line is: z0
- one line is: y0+z0

(all of them plotted as function of `x$t`)

I know that it's possible to do this by transforming the list into a `data.frame` and then reshaping the data.frame to long format and then for each value there will be a category, and then I can use ggplot2 to plot `y0` and `z0` (though I do not know how to plot `z0+y0` with ggplot), but is there an easier way to do this? An alternative way?

EDIT.

I forgot to add my data. Here it is:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8clGpnMSCjUdTRXNjBNMktkdVE

Comment: Base plotting is happy with vectors (or matrices, depending), but ggplot _really_ wants you to pass it a data.frame.

Comment: Is it really possible to do couple of lines from the same vector using the inner `plot` function, I have checked several tutorials and almost all of them look as complicated as the ggplot approach and some of them did not even work for my particular data.

Comment: Unless it's a time series, pretty much no, though you can add them with `lines`. Really, in the time you spend sorting out how to do it in base, you can probably munge your data.frame into the right format. `purrr` and `tidyr` may be helpful.